# How to tranfer data from Teradata to Greenplum using Python?

Tags: python, teradata, greenplum

I am using Python to establish a connection to greenplum and run codes automatically. For that I am using these drivers ­   psycopg2,­  psycopg2.extensions & psycopg2.extras. I also have to establish a connection to Teradata and run some codes and tranfer tables from Teradata to greenplum. Can someone please suggest some drivers or method to do this? I heard that arrays or alteryx can be used in python to do so but i couldn't anything.

Comment: Is it possible to use ODBC connection drivers? Google says they exist for Greenplumb. If you can use ODBC drivers for both databases you can use pyodbc to execute SQL. Here is a very simple look at ODBC data movement using pyodbc http://stackoverflow.com/a/26727920/2573907. (You will not want to use volatile tables).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the data volumes are at least moderate in size - 10's of millions or greater.

1. FastExport or Teradata Parallel Transport Export of the Teradata data to a
   flat file or named pipe.
2. Ingesting using Greenplum's preferred method for bulk
       loading data from a flat file or named pipe.

Other options may include invoking a Teradata FastExport API via JDBC using Python but then you still have to figure out how to efficiently ingest the data via Greenplum.